# Scaling up AMSBOOK -class based documents fails

Tags: geometry, scaling, amsbook

I have found impossible to scale up documents created by AMSBOOK -documentclass.

Bottom on this question is a minimalistic TeX -file.  You may find the text familiar.

1. If the first two lines are

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
   %\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
   ```

Document fails

2. If the two first lines are

   ```
   %\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
   \documentclass[a4paper]{book}
   ```

LaTeXing goes smoothly

I have tried  \usepackage{geometry} -package and  \usepackage{blowup}  -package and \mag -command with AMSBOOK with same results.

Both packages and \mag -command Works fine with BOOK -documentclass and also other documentclasses I have tried.

What is needed to make AMSBOOK -based documents scalable ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
%\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage{newcent}
%\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, mag=1095, height=22.3truecm, width=12.7cm,showframe=true,verbose=true}
%\geometry{a4paper, mag=1095}
%\usepackage{blowup}
%\blowUp{paper=x1.09545}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Meet the American Mathematical Society}
A professional society since 1888, we advance research and connect the diverse global mathematical community through publications, 
meetings and conferences, MathSciNet, professional services, advocacy, and awareness programs.

\section{Supporting}
Some 30,000 individuals and 570 institutions worldwide make up the Society. AMS membership supports the mathematical sciences by providing 
access to research, professional networking, conferences and events, advocacy, and a connection to a 
community passionate about mathematics and its relationship to other disciplines and everyday life:
\end{document}
```

Comment: latex doesn't really support `\mag` at all, the main difference between amsbook and book is that in some places it uses true lengths as in `\oddsidemargin.5truein` so the margin is not scaled by `\mag`. If you really need that then simplest would be to make a local copy under a different name and remove `true` everywhere. (But why use `\mag` normally it is easy enough to just scale to PDF if needed)

Comment: About 25 years ago I used DVIPS to produce up-scaled documents.  Since then I have been using pdflatex only with package blowup.  I have been able to scale AMSART -based documents, for example, without any difficulties.  The scaling the PDF -file will be my last option, of course it works but it would be much easier to used geometry -package for scaling and fine-tuning.

Answer (score 1):

The example can be simplified to this plain tex

```
\hsize=10truein

\mag=1095


zzz
\bye
```

which gives the same error:

```
! Incompatible magnification (1095);
 the previous value will be retained (1000).
```

You can not change `\mag` after you have used `true` dimensions. If you set `\mag` earlier then it runs without error:

```
\mag1095
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
%\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage{newcent}
%\usepackage{palatino}
%\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, , height=22.3truecm, width=12.7cm,showframe=true,verbose=true}
%\geometry{a4paper, mag=1095}
%\usepackage{blowup}
%\blowUp{paper=x1.09545}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Meet the American Mathematical Society}
A professional society since 1888, we advance research and connect the diverse global mathematical community through publications, 
meetings and conferences, MathSciNet, professional services, advocacy, and awareness programs.

\section{Supporting}
Some 30,000 individuals and 570 institutions worldwide make up the Society. AMS membership supports the mathematical sciences by providing 
access to research, professional networking, conferences and events, advocacy, and a connection to a 
community passionate about mathematics and its relationship to other disciplines and everyday life:
\end{document}
```

Comment: I replaced all true dimensions from my copy of AMSBOOK.  They all seems to be in the one place in the end of the file, thanks @DavidCarlisle !  Now LaTeXing works without errors when I am using `\geometry` or `\blowup` -packages with different scaling options.  The results are surpraising though.  I need to examine more the behaviour of different documentclasses with scaling options before commenting more.